# Sharing a GNU Screen Session

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I have a meeting with a professor coming up shortly, but he won't be at school for a face-to-face meeting. Instead he will meet with me via Skype and an SSH login.  I'm a heavy user of GNU Screen, but I've never used its multiuser functionality before.  How would I go about setting up multiuser capabilities, and what would be good permissions to give him (i.e. r/w/x)?

Comment: AFAIK, for multi user, screen has be installed setuid root, which now a days no administrators like. my information may be dated, since I don't see an essential need for it to be setuid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Good tutorial [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20090419014053/http://linuxhacks.org/tutorials/jakes_gnu_screen_tutorial.php). See [this part](http://web.archive.org/web/20150321172416/http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/screen-3.9.4/html_chapter/screen_8.html) of the GNU screen manual on how to set ACL permissions. Give him whatever permission you think he needs, though I don't think you'd need to change it from the default that's given by `acladd`.

Comment: fixed it for you

Comment: Looks like both first link and alternate link is broken.

Comment: Fixed the archive.org link

Comment: Please include essential parts of the linked article in your answer. This is a good example why link-only answers aren't welcome - when links rot, the answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 19):

Inside your own screen session do the following (I am *bob* and want to share my screen with *fred*)

```
^A :multiuser on
^A :acladd fred
```

then tell fred to type:

```
$ screen -x bob/
```

`screen` has to be installed as suid root for this to work. (`sudo chmod +s /usr/bin/screen`, this could be a security risk)

there is more information about the acl-syntax on the [screen man page](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/package/epics/extensions/iocConsole/screen.1.html) - it is possible to share a screen session read only, for example